# Filename too long when using keyword_search to detect pdf?

Tags: r, text-mining, pdftools

I am trying to do some text mining of a pdf by searching for certain keywords.

This is my code:

```
library(pdftools)
library(tidyverse)
library(pdfsearch)

UC_text <- pdf_text("https://wilmar-iframe.todayir.com/attachment/20190411162436345449392_en.pdf") 

result <- keyword_search(UC_text, 
                         keyword = c('SUBSTANTIAL SHAREHOLDERS'),
                         path = TRUE, surround_lines = 1)
```

However, I got the error message of a filename too long. How can I get over this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the explanation in the cran manual of pdfsearch, you can directly pass the PDF link to the `keyword_search()`. In this way, I do not see the error message you provided. I rather got the following result.

```
result <- keyword_search("https://wilmar-iframe.todayir.com/attachment/20190411162436345449392_en.pdf", 
                         keyword = c('SUBSTANTIAL SHAREHOLDERS'),
                         path = TRUE, surround_lines = 1)

  keyword                  page_num line_num line_text token_text
  <chr>                       <int>    <int> <list>    <list>    
1 SUBSTANTIAL SHAREHOLDERS       49     2010 <chr [3]> <list [3]>
```

Comment: in this case, I won't be able to parse multiple pdf if i directly pass that link in keyword_search?

Comment: and even though 'substantial shareholders' appeared multiple times, why is it the results only showed one record?

Comment: @Jane I think you can parse multiple files if you use loops. As for the result, I have no clue. That document has more than 200 pages. I am afraid I do not have time to look into all pages. What you wanna do is to see how texts are imported to R. As far as I experiences, dealing with PDF text data requires tons of efforts to arrange clean text data.